# Can boost serialization be explicitly backwards-compatible?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization

We use [`boost::archive::binary_iarchive` and `binary_oarchive`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html) here, and run into the following issue once in a while: a developer upgrades his local Boost-version and now the data-blobs produced by his program are not readable by others, forcing them to upgrade too.

There have not been a problem in the other direction: de-serialization of data written by older Boost-versions works in newer version. Which means, the serializer's version is recorded in the data-file...

I see, that `binary_oarchive` takes a `flags` argument (which defaults to zero). Perhaps, we can request, that serializer creates blobs readable by earlier versions of itself using a flag?

Any other way to ensure, that, for example, when serializing with Boost-1.75, the archives are understood by, at least, Boost-1.65?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a different library? I ran into this same issue and changed to Cereal. It has a very similar syntax to boost.

Comment: Agree with previous comment. Boost.Serialization could be more robust and compact. If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015339/boost-serialization-archive-unsupported-version-exception) doesn't help, check out Cereal, or [capnproto](https://capnproto.org/cxx.html).

Comment: Or Oops, which is the most robust solution from compatibility point of view: https://bitbucket.org/barczpe/oops